# Combining a join and a complex select in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am quite new to using LINQ and C# in general, and am trying to re-factor an existing API from node/express to learn how it works (my first project in C#).

I believe I have found answers to this question that I am struggling to understand because I am using lambda functions and those answers, by and large, are not. This query was fully functional before I started expanding it to add the join (eg everything from the where/orderby portion)

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PitchingSeason>>> GetSeasonPitching(
[FromQuery] int season, [FromQuery] string? team, [FromQuery] int ip = 1)
        {
            var query = await _context.Masterpitching
            .Join(_context.Teams,
            pitching => pitching.TeamId,
            team => team.TeamId,
            (pitching, team) =>{??}) <-- not sure what to do here
            .Select(obj => new PitchingSeason()) <-- or how to use the class here
            .Where(
            obj => obj.Season == season 
                && obj.Ip > ip
                && (team == null || obj.TeamId == team))
            .OrderBy(obj => obj.Fip)
            .ToListAsync();
            return query;
        }
```

for comparison, here is the query I am attempting to replicate from node.pg.   The PitchingSeason class includes all the keys that I select in this query.     The final statement of the join and how to use the class to do the select is where I am getting stuck

```
pool.query(`SELECT p.gidp,p.player,p.np,p.season,p.sho,p.bk,p.sv,p.bb,p.so,p.wp,p.hb,
p.rs,p.l,p.cg,p.player_id,p.gs,p.ibb,p.team_id,p.hr,p.era,p.fip,
p.hld,p.g,p.ip,p.w,p.r,p.er,t.name_abbrev,t.league_abbrev,t.name
FROM "${season}pitching" AS p INNER JOIN teams AS t ON p.team_id = t.team_id
 WHERE p.ip > $1 ORDER BY fip ASC`, search)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join's third parameter is a function that creates a new object with the two joined items. You can see an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.8).

What you probably want to do here is create the PitchingSeason on where your question marks are like so:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PitchingSeason>>> GetSeasonPitching(
[FromQuery] int season, [FromQuery] string? team, [FromQuery] int ip = 1)
        {
            var query = await _context.Masterpitching
            .Join(_context.Teams,
            pitching => pitching.TeamId,
            team => team.TeamId,
            (pitching, team) => new PitchingSeason(/*Fill PitchingSeason from pitching and team*/)) 
            .Where(
            obj => obj.Season == season 
                && obj.Ip > ip
                && (team == null || obj.TeamId == team))
            .OrderBy(obj => obj.Fip)
            .ToListAsync();
            return query;
        }
```

So the next Where will get PitchingSeason types, and filter on their Season, Ip, TeamId.

Edit: what you see in the linked example is an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). You could also use it, but you'd need to change the Where, instead of obj.TeamId, you'd have obj.Team.TeamId, assuming you create a new type with `new {Pitching = pitching, Team = team}`

Comment: Alright thats what I originally thought.   There's no way to have the class map the keys from the object without going through and specifying each key/value pair, is there?  

If I do it that way I don't even need the .Select, do I?  

That is easier than I anticipated, if a little more tedious.